# Hello, I'm trying to get my code to read, decrypt or encrypt a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get my code to read, decrypt or encrypt a text file, but I'm not getting it I've been trying for a week and nothing, if anyone can help me, I'll leave it below, until the encryption and decryption of words I got.

I've tried using the Panda library, I've tried using the open function and several other things and nothing, it can't read. Here's the code as far as I was able to do it.

```py
import string

all_letters = string.ascii_letters

while True:
    print(42*"-")
    print("Programa de criptografia de substituições:")
    print(42*"-")
    print("[1]-criptografar uma palavra")
    print("[2]-descriptografar uma palavra")
    print("[3]-sair")
    print(42*"-")
    A = input("Escolha uma opção: ")
    key = 1

    if A == "1":
        dict1 = {}
        for i in range(len(all_letters)):
            dict1[all_letters[i]] = all_letters[(i + key) % len(all_letters)]
        print(42*"-")
        print("-> [1]-criptografar uma palavra <-")
        print(42*"-")
        plain_txt = input("Escreva sua frase: ")
        cipher_txt = []

        print("\nTrocas na Criptografia:")
 
        for char in plain_txt:
            if char in all_letters:
                temp = dict1[char]
                cipher_txt.append(temp)
                print(f"{char} -> {temp}")  
            else:
                temp = char
                cipher_txt.append(temp)

        cipher_txt = "".join(cipher_txt)
        print("\nO Texto cifrado é:", cipher_txt)

    if A == "2":
        dict2 = {}
        for i in range(len(all_letters)):
            dict2[all_letters[i]] = all_letters[(i - key) % len(all_letters)]
        print(42*"-")
        print("-> [2]-descriptografar uma palavra <-")
        print(42*"-")
        cipher_txt = input("Escreva o texto cifrado: ")
        decrypt_txt = []

        print("\nTrocas na Descriptografia:")
       
        for char in cipher_txt:
            if char in all_letters:
                temp = dict2[char]
                decrypt_txt.append(temp)
                print(f"{char} -> {temp}") 
            else:
                temp = char
                decrypt_txt.append(temp)

        decrypt_txt = "".join(decrypt_txt)
        print("\nA descrição é:", decrypt_txt)

    if A == "3":
        print(42*"-")
        print("-> [3]-sair <-")
        print(42*"-")
        print("Programa encerrado c/sucesso!")
        break
```

Comment: Your code seems to work. What is the issue you are running into? Is it working with files rather than strings?

Comment: yes, it works normally, my difficulty is getting it to do this with files, it is getting it to encrypt or decrypt the words in the file through a txt file.